# How to stop UIView from rotating, without View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, capacitor

I am currently working on a Capacitor plugin, and so my control over the UIView/Controller stack is somewhat limited.  What I am trying to do is display my plugin view, underneath the Capacitor webView.  The Capacitor Plugin framework provides a `BridgeViewController`, which controls a `WKWebView` (the Capacitor webView).  `BridgeViewController` is also the `rootViewController`, and so the `webView`'s parent is just a `UIView` without a View Controller.

I'm able to make my plugin display underneath the Capacitor webView, by doing the following:

```swift
self.bridge.viewController.view.superview?.addSubview(self.myPluginViewController.view)
self.bridge.viewController.view.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self.webView)
```

where `bridge.view` returns the webView.  The issue however, is that `self.myPluginViewController`'s lifecycle methods no longer fire.  Unfortunately, since `bridge` is the `rootViewController`, `bridge.view.superview` has no controller.

I've also tried:

```swift
self.bridge.viewController.addChild(self.myPluginViewController)
self.bridge.viewController.view.superview?.addSubview(self.myPluginViewController.view)
self.bridge.viewController.view.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self.webView)
```

but that throws a `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency` error.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this?  Is it possible to add `myPluginViewController` to `bridge` as a sibling to the webView?  Alternatively, is there a way to add `myPluginViewController.view` directly to another view, while retaining the lifecycle methods?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/

Comment: I dont think that helps me too much.  The view within `self.bridge.viewController` is a `WKWebView`, which I cant add my plugin view to.  I need for my plugin view to be a sibling of that view.  Unfortunately, there aren't any ViewController parents of `self.bridge.viewController` as it is the root view.  So the only parent I have access to is a `UIView`, rather than a `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

The situation you've described doesn't sound completely accurate. Every view on screen has a parent and (somewhere up the tree) a view controller. If your view is the "root" that either means that you're actually referring to the window, or the superview is a window.

With that out of the way, for a view controller to receive lifecycle messages it needs to be a child of the actual root view controller of the window. iOS requires that all apps have a root view controller (starting in iOS 7 I think). That means that you either are looking in the wrong place for the root view controller, or you already have it and don't realize it.

An easy way to get the root view controller is to use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController`. It's deprecated, but it should help you at least find the root view controller. Once you've identified what view controller is actually the root you can architect a non-deprecated way of accessing it. My guess is that you'll have to get the AppDelegate involved.

Comment: I believe the `bridge.viewController` which controls `webView` is the `rootViewController`.  I put a breakpoint in, and inspected both the bridge viewController the capacitor plugin framework gives me, and `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController`, and they have the same memory address.  The problem seems to be, I cant figure out how to add a sibling viewController to the rootViewController/bridgeViewController.

Comment: If its the root view controller then it can't have siblings.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of..  To get a full understanding of what I am grabbing, `rootViewController.view.superview` would then point to the window (which is also a UIView)?

Comment: As long as things haven't been tampered with, yes, it would be the window. You can verify that by checking to see if it's of type `UIWindow`.